# Adjusting height of \left(, \right), etc

Tags: equations, formatting, height

For aesthetic reasons, I prefer the aspect of the first equation in the following example to the second.

```
\begin{align}
\Big\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\Big\|_p^p&=\int_X\Big|\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\Big|^p\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_X\big(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n\,\big)\mathrm{d}\mu,\\
\left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\right\|_p^p&=\int_X\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\right|^p\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_X\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n\,\right)\mathrm{d}\mu.
\end{align}
```

[image]

I think it goes without saying, but what I want is for the parentheses to fit the height of the operators but leave out the subscripts and superscripts.

**The problem.** I want to modify a previous document written with style (2) and convert it to style (1). I'm afraid I'll have to do it by hand, since there are going to be numerous `\left(` and `\right)` in some equations that won't need to be modified.

**The question.** Is there a way to redefine `\left(`, `\right)`, `\left[`, etc. to adapt them to this behavior?

Comment: You can increase the value of `\delimitershortfall`. The defaults is `delimitershortfall=5pt`.

Comment: Use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, not the simple `\Big`. Possibly `\biggl` and `\biggr` for `\sum`. And no, there is not really an automatic way.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I will do it by hand and try your suggestions

Comment: @JuanCastaño In addendum it is preferible to use \Bigl or other similar forms especially when you split an equation to have not of the mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with some effort. The secret is not to try to change `\left` and `\right` but rather to change `\sum`.

`xparse` (now built in to LaTeX) allows you to define commands with embellishments. Here's our redefined `\sum` command:

```
\let\oldsum=\sum % ➊

\RenewDocumentCommand{\sum}{e{_^}}{ % ➋
  \vphantom{\oldsum} % ➌
  \mathop{\smash{\oldsum % ➍
    \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}} % ➎
    \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}
  }}
}
```

We copy `\sum` to a new name ➊ so we can use the old value. We then define a new version of `\sum` using the embellishment support ➋ to grab the subscript (if present) and put it in argument `#1` and the superscript (if present) and put it in argument `#2`. Then we make sure we reserve the amount of vertical space the original operator uses without superscripts and subscripts ➌, then we will use `\smash` to remove the height and depth of the sum we're building and also wrap it in `\mathop` so we still get operator spacing ➍. Finally, we check to see if we had superscripts and subscripts ➎ and if they're present, we typeset them on the `\smash`'d `\sum`.

Comment: Good thinking!!! It works fine, :-)