# xparse embellishment not capturing all inside of braces

Tags: macros, xparse

I am currently learning, playing with xparse, and have the following demo command partially working:

```latex
\let\oldlog\log
\RenewDocumentCommand{\log}{s m e{_^}}{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathrm{log}%
        \IfValueT{#3}{_#3}%
        \IfValueT{#4}{^#4}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\!\left(#2\right)}{#2}%
    }%
}
```

My issue is the current result. What I expect is that `\log{x}^{yy}_{zzz}` gives:

[image: expected]

But instead, I get this:

[image: actual]

Why doesn't the embellishment argument, `e{_^}` capture the whole content in the braces for `^{yy}` and `_{zzz}`?

Comment: What's the advantage over typing `\log_{zzz}^{yy}(x)`?

Comment: @egreg In this case, nothing. I am just learning xparse, and this was easy enough to do. I spent 30 or more minutes wrapping my head around this issue with embellishments, thinking it was some kind of extra layer of complexity.

Comment: Just remember that the correct syntax for subscript and superscripts is *always* with braces, that sometimes can be omitted. More to the point, the braces around a mandatory argument are always stripped off by TeX and in this case you need to supply them back.

Comment: For an example of a  non-trivial use of embellishments, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602341/202780

Comment: @egreg Yup! Just one of those silly mistakes that is obvious in hindsight!

Comment: You should also seriously use either `\oldlog` or `\operatorname{log}` instead of `\mathrm{log}`. Also avoid using `\left...\right` in general and stick to manual scaling. And if you must use automatic scaling, use the variants from the package `mleftright` where some spacing issues are being fixed.

Comment: @Gaussler I didn't know about `\operatorname`, thanks for that! I read the amsmath package and it said `\mathrm` is a better alternative to many others, so that is nice to know. As for `\left ... \right`, I have never ever had any issues with it. Can you provide some extra material as to why I should have that opinion? Thanks :)

Comment: The main problem with `\left...\right` is that they have a tendency to make the delimiters way too big. Look at `\[ \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \]` to see what I mean. In this case, `\Bigl( ... \Bigr)` or `\biggl(...\biggr)` yield better results. Apart from that, there are certain spacing issues, but [they can be fixed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right).

Comment: My recommendation on `\left` and `\right` is to prefer them over manual scaling unless otherwise necessary. They are usually correct and there are some instances where they're necessary (e.g., if you want to write the open interval ]-1,0] which will be typeset incorrectly without using `\left]` and `\right]`. Not to mention cases where `\Bigg` isn't bigggg enough or incorrect sizing without amsmath in anything that's not ten point.

Comment: @DonHosek Well, it seems to me that most TeX gurus give the opposite recommendation. As you know, commands `\left` and `\right` don’t even give the delimiters `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` status. On top of that, `\left...\right` change the positioning of indices: `\left(...\right)^2` vs. `(...)^2`. The interval ]–1,0] can be typed `\mathopen]-1,0]`, or, preferably, via some command (e.g. via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, the `interval` package, or some custom solution; nobody will be surprised to learn that mine is based on `semantex`).

Comment: @Gaussler If most TeX gurus ar giving the opposite recommendation, they're wrong. See, for example, *The TeXbook* p. 149 (although perhaps you don't consider that author to be particularly knowledgable about TeX). You may also want to familiarize yourself with the definitions of the various biggg commands, and I have no idea where your claim about `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` comes from. That same unknowledgeable author gives as his primary suggestion for the open interval `\left]`…`\right` with `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` as a secondary suggestion.

Comment: @DonHosek The spacing issues with `\left...\right` are documented everywhere on this site. I agree that my previous formulation about not making them behave like `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` was misleading, but it doesn’t change the facts. I know that the biggg commands are defined in terms of `\left...\right`; that does not change the fact that `\left...\right` lead to both bad spacing and too big delimiters. I have no doubt that Knuth intended them to be used the way you suggest, but nowadays, the common consensus is that he made a wrong design choice in this particular case.

Comment: @Gaussler You're making a bunch of claims without being able to back them up. I'm not going to waste time arguing about phantom issues and phantom gurus. Your one specific claim is a spurious one. No one would say that *all* delimiters should be marked with `\left` and `\right`, just ones that need to be resized. (btw you misspelled wrong in your reply, it doesn't start with m-i-s-)

Comment: @DonHosek What phantom claims? [The spacing issues are well-documented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right) (and there are 500 other questions here documenting the same). And @DavidCarlisle explicitly states in the comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611835/19809) that there are **no** benefits of the `\mathinner` atom that is added by `\left...\right`.

Answer (score 3):

Ooof I worked it out; Turns out you need `_{#3}` and `^{#4}`.

```latex
\let\oldlog\log
\RenewDocumentCommand{\log}{s m e{_^}}{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathrm{log}%
        \IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
        \IfValueT{#4}{^{#4}}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\!\left(#2\right)}{#2}%
    }%
}
```